# Firestore query with orderBy and "not in" on different fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to perform a query with `orderBy` and `not-in` on different fields:

```
.where("field1", "not-in", ["a", "b", "c"])
.orderBy("field2", "desc")
```

`not-in` is not mentioned in the [ordering limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations), so it seems possible:

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your
> first ordering must be on the same field

But in the [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) `not-in` seems to have the same limitations:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in)
> comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this directly and got the following error message:

> FirebaseError: Invalid query. You have a where filter with an
> inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) on field 'field1' and so you
> must also use 'field1' as your first argument to Query.orderBy(), but
> your first orderBy() is on field 'field2' instead.

So the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) is lacking, will post a ticket